# Retrieval during Rehashing in Concurrent HashMap

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, hashmap, concurrenthashmap

I have read about the implementation of ConcurrentHashMap which states:

> ConcurrentHashMap does not block when performing retrieval
> operations, and there is no locking for the usual operations.

So let's say we call `put()` method and `get()` method simultaneously: if `put()` performs rehashing don't we need to synchronize the `get()` method? The `get()` method will determine the bucket using `hash % N` (where N is size of the hashmap). Shouldn't the bucket calculation method of `get()` be impacted because of rehashing?

Comment: No, you don't need to worry about this. The class has been specifically designed to handle this.

Answer (score 3):

Rehashing only occurs when re-sizing the hash table.

If `get()` is called *during* the re-size operation, then the `put()` hasn't completed yet, so the `get()` won't see the new value, which is as it should be.

Remember, the table bins are in an array, and arrays are fixed-size, so re-sizing means an entirely new hash table. That new hash table is not available to other threads until the re-size has completed. Until then, all other threads calling `get()` will see the old hash table.

Comment: Thanks for the help.